# Changing block position in Bartik theme

Tags: theming

I am using bartik theme to develop a website.I need the User menu and search block to be beside the logo and main menu block to be below the logo.
But all the menu and search blocks[image] appear below the logo.How can I move the user menu and search block to right top corner of the page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can change a position of menu and search block from structure > block link and assign it to *** custom made region ***, also use custom css can fix your problem.

also you can Demonstrate  the all region of theme from admin/structure/block/demo/bartik

hope this will help you